# Understanding bounds of concatenated arrays in Ada 2012

Tags: arrays, ada, ada2012

I am reading *Programming in Ada 2012* by John Barnes. In section 8.6 he discusses array concatenation and the rules for array bounds, in particular:

> The lower bound of the result depends on whether the underlying array **type** is 
>   constrained or not. If it is unconstrained...then the lower bound is
>   that of the left operand...[otherwise] the lower bound is that of the array index subtype.

Then in the exercises for 8.6, question 7 is as follows (I've added the answers given on the website PDF inside the [] ):

> 7. Given
>
> > type TC is array (1..10) of Integer;
> >       type TU is array (Natural range <>) of Integer;
> >       AC: TC;
> >       AU: TU(1..10);    
> >     
> >     What are the bounds of:
> >
> > ```
> > (a) AC(6..10) & AC(1..5)           [1..10]        
> > (b) AC(6) & AC(7..10) & AC(1..5)   [1..10]   
> > (c) AU(6..10)& AU(1..5)            [6..15]  
> > (d) AU(6) & AU(7..10) & AU(1..5)   [0..9]
> > ```

The answers to a and b made sense to me since the AC array is based on a **constrained** type we just use the bounds of the index. I would think the answers to c and should both be 6..15 since the underlying type is **unconstrained** the leftmost operand AU(6) or AU(6..10) will determine the starting bounds. Then I tried coding it up as shown below to better understand and all four show the bounds as 1..10. Is my code wrong, are the answers wrong or is the description in the text wrong?  (BTW, I also coded with new array variables and made the assignments to those but the results are the same).

```
type TC is array (1..10) of Integer;
type TU is array (Natural range <>) of Integer;
AC: TC;
AU: TU(1..10);

begin
  AC := AC(6..10) & AC(1..5); 
  Tio.Put("7a) Constrained type starting with 6..10  ");
  Iio.Put(AC'First); Iio.Put(AC'Last); Tio.New_Line;

  Tio.Put ("7b) Constrained type starting with 6      ");
  AC := AC(6) & AC(7..10) & AC(1..5); -- 7.b
  Iio.Put(AC'First); Iio.Put(AC'Last); Tio.New_Line;

  Tio.Put ("7c) Unconstrained type starting with 6..10");
  AU := AU(6..10) & AU(1..5);
  Iio.Put(AU'First); Iio.Put(AU'Last); Tio.New_Line;
  Tio.Put_Line("Answer keys says 6..15");

  Tio.Put ("7d) Unconstrained type starting with 6    ");
  AU := AU(6) & AU(7..10)& AU(1..5);
  Iio.Put(AU'First); Iio.Put(AU'Last); Tio.New_Line;
  Tio.Put_Line("Answer key says 0..9 - Why not 6..15???");
```

(Tio and Iio are just renames of the std Ada io packages for text and integer)

When run, this code produces the following console output:

```
E:\Google Drive\SW_DEV\Ada\Sample\obj\hello
7a) Constrained type starting with 6..10            1         10
7b) Constrained type starting with 6                1         10
7c) Unconstrained type starting with 6..10          1         10
Answer keys says 6..15
7d) Unconstrained type starting with 6              1         10
Answer key says 0..9 - Why not 6..15???
```

Comment: One comment to (d) : the left operand has no bounds (it is an Integer not an array), and the lower bound of Natural is 0, so I can believe the sample answer...

Comment: Brian's comment is the correct answer about (d).  The rule is in [RM 4.5.3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-5-3.html), paragraph 9.  This rule says that the left operand, since it is not an array, is treated as an array whose bounds are 0..0 (it's 0 because `TU`'s index subtype is `Natural`, and the lower bound of `Natural` is 0).  If it were `AU(6..6)` instead of `AU(6)`, the values would be the same but the bounds would be 6..15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your AU is defined to start with lower bound of 1 (an anonymous array subtype with range 1..10). That will *never* change.

For the unconstrained results (c and d) you should assign to a new variable, like this:

```
declare
   AU_c : TU := AU(6..10) & AU(1..5);
   AU_d : TU := AU(6) & AU(7..10)& AU(1..5);
begin
   -- your Put/Put_Lines here
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. Between your answer and the comment from  @Brian above it all now makes much more sense.